# Narrowing down the gaps for categorical y-axis labels on a coef plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, coefplot

I am struggling with narrowing down the space between my y-axis categorical variables. I thought about using dummy variables and then editing it out to do so. Any tips or advices?

I have tried to change the y-axis spacing and then making the variables name shorter but nothing seems to be working so far.

Comment: Generally, the y axis fills the space of the plot. If you want a smaller y-axis, then you should reduce the size  of the plot - either by making the window shorter (for an interactive display) or by reducing the height (if you are saving the plot to a file).

Comment: If you need more help than that, please share some sample data and sample code - either use a built-in data set to illustrate the problem, share code to create a little sample data that can be used, or use `dput()` on a subset of your data to create R code to recreate it. (Running `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will create R code to reproduce the first 10 rows of `your_data`.)